# Puntero constante a struct volatile

Tags: c, punteros

En mi implementación, utilizo un puntero a una `struct` que **puede ser modificada** en cualquier momento **desde mi código**; quiero que, desde el **exterior** de **mi** código, se pueda acceder a ese puntero, pero **solo para lectura** (para poder usarlo en ciertas funciones de utilidad).

```
struct Thread;

extern volatile struct Thread *const CurrentThread;
```

1. Es necesario que sea `volatile` porque se cambiará desde un
   manejador de interrupciones (de momento, solo para Unix), y quiero
   que el compilador lo sepa.
2. Es crítica (muchas funciones *usarán*
   ese puntero, puede que desde el propio manejador de interrupciones), por lo que en principio no quiero usar una función que
   devuelva una copia del mismo (para garantizar la *solo lectura*).
3. Ese puntero selecciona una tarea de entre un conjunto de ellas. Una modificación *descontrolada* producirá efectos, cuanto menos, *curiosos*.

Siempre es posible hacer un cast, pero por lo menos que el compilador *avise* si se intenta cambiar su valor *por descuido*.

Las preguntas son:

- ¿ Es correcta esa declaración para conseguir los objetivos descritos
  ?
- Si la respuesta es negativa, ¿ Como se pueden conseguir los efectos buscados ?

**EDITO** - Para dejar la pregunta algo más clara y concreta:

Puntero a `struct`:

```
struct Thread *
```

Puntero **constante** a `struct` (el puntero en sí mismo no se puede modificar):

```
struct Thread *const
```

Puntero **constante** a `struct`. **Nosotros** no podemos cambiar el valor del puntero, pero este puede cambiar en cualquier momento fuera del control del compilador:

```
volatile struct Thread *const
```

¿ Es esto último correcto ?

Answer (score 1):

No existe ningún mecanismo que impida que desde fuera manipulen esa posición de memoria o las adyacentes (si no fuese así no existirían las vulnerabilidades a partir de desbordamiento de buffer).

Lo que puedes hacer es proporcionar una copia del objeto

```
extern volatile struct Thread *const CurrentThread;

struct Thread CopiaDelObjeto()
{
  return *CurrentThread;
};
```

Al devolver el elemento por valor cualquier cambio que hagan sobre el mismo será local y no se reflejará en tu propio objeto. Esto funciona bien hasta que la estructura tiene punteros internos. En este caso puedes optar por crear una *versión reducida* de la estructura que no incluya punteros y devolver un objeto de este segundo tipo.

La primera solución tampoco funcionará si tu idea es que quien coja una copia del puntero la use como un *observador*. En este caso lo mejor sería establecer un sistema de avisos (tipo patrón *Observer* o con eventos) de tal forma que cualquiera que quiera estar al tanto de la evolución del objeto simplemente tendrá que suscribirse.

Comment: En la pregunta ya dejé entrever que, a unas malas, **siempre** podrán modificar el puntero (mediante un cast, por ejemplo); el objetivo es que por lo menos el compilador *avise* con un `warning` o un `error` de ese cambio si se hace *por descuido*, no *impedir* el cambio, cosa como dices imposible. Resumiendo: no ponerselo *en bandeja*l; que tenga que hacerlo *mediante fuerza bruta*.

Comment: El uso final del puntero es usarlo en una serie de *macros* que devuelvan ciertos datos. **Yo** si conozco los datos internos de la estructura.

Comment: ¿Y no sería entonces más correcto que la interfaz en vez de devolver el objeto te ofreciese la información que extraes con esas macros? Exponer el objeto implica que si la estructura del mismo cambia te tocará recompilar las librerías del tercero so pena de que el programa empiece a funcionar de forma errática.

Comment: Siempre puedes hacer una función que devuelva un puntero constante... pero en C, que no se caracteriza precisamente por un tipado fuerte, eso no significa demasiado

Comment: Exacto. Pero la librería es la mía ;-) Las macros se ajustan a cada versión de la librería. Ya pensé en lo de hacer funciones auxiliares, pero *quiero ver si es posible con macros*, por lo del rendimiento (y porque como es posible usarlas en un manejador de interrupciones, quiero tener el tamaño de la pila controlada). Digamos que es un capricho.

Comment: @Trauma Un consejo. No te preocupes por el rendimiento hasta que puedas probarlo. Meter macros o funciones inline puede hacer que pierdas el principio de localidad de la caché lo que obliga a repaginar y el beneficio que supuestamente consigues al evitar llamadas a función se ve sobrepasado por el sobrecoste de recargar la caché... por ponerte un ejemplo.Habrá casos en lo que comentas te funcionará pero habrá otros en los que no. Deja que sea un profiler el que te diga cuándo debes hacerlo.

Comment: Te entiendo, ya pensé en eso (creando una única función que devuelva diversa info), por ejemplo `void statThread( int INFO_TO_GET, void *WHERE )` para que *cuele* en la cache. Si mayormente es, como te comenté antes, un *capricho*. Es que no se si la declaración es correcta (compilar compila) para lo que pretendo. Y de paso aprendo ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Una de las cosas que he aprendido de C es que los modificadores (volatile, register, inline...) muchas veces no significan lo que deberían, y los compiladores incluso los ignoran.

Con `volatile`, hasta donde sé, evitas que el compilador asuma cosas para optimizar el código. En realidad, cualquier dato podría ser modificado por otro código que no tengas en cuenta, aunque no esté marcado como `volatile`.

A la primera pregunta no sé responderte, pero para ocultar en C el contenido de las estructuras yo siempre he hecho lo siguiente.

Como alternativa puedes declarar el puntero como `void*`. De esa forma, el usuario tiene que, forzosamente, convertirlo a la estructura para escribir. Para leer puedes ofrecer funciones que reciban ese `void*` (porque tú conoces la configuración de la estructura), y devuelvan el dato leído.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, @lilezek. Si, ya conozco esa técnica. He editado la pregunta para aclararla y concretarla, que se me fué el santo al cielo con el *bosque* y no vi bien el *arbol* :-)

Comment: ¿De todos modos, el const no debería ir delante de Thread? Algo así: `volatile struct const Thread * CurrentThread`

Comment: Nop. Si lo pones delante, es un `puntero NO constante a dato constante`.

Comment: Pensé que era eso lo que se pedía.

Comment: El problema de la pregunta es que es **dificil** de comprobar. Lo de `const` es fácil, el propio compilador te avisa. Lo del `volatile` es mas difícil, habría que mirar la salida en ensamblador, y posiblemente compararlas.

Comment: En lo referente a `volatile`, te equivocas. **Ningún** código puede modificarse fuera del control del compilador, ya que lo modificas *tu*; el compilador lleva la cuenta de a que variables accedes y desde donde. El propio programa se ejecuta de forma secuencial, y al compilador no le resulta difícil llevar esas cuentas. **Excepciones**: uso de hilos, respuestas a interrupciones, y uso de código ASM `inline` mal usado. Para esos casos es para lo que está `volatile`. Los primeros 2 se *saltan* la secuencialidad, y el 3º accede a los datos *fuera* del control del compilador.

Comment: Yo no he dicho que un código se modifique, aunque eso no es cierto. El kernel podría reescribir el código si quisiera. He dicho que esa variable podría ser modificada, si el kernel de tu sistema operativo lo permite, usando algún tipo de puntero lejano. Las respuestas a interrupciones de hecho son una forma parecida a esta: el kernel en vez de devolver la ejecución a tu programa se la devuelve a un controlador de interrupciones. Con `volatile` el compilador **asume** que no hay exclusión mutua ni atomicidad en las operaciones relacionadas con ese dato.

Comment: No me referia a eso, no me has entendido. Quiero decir que todo acceso a datos **en tu codigo fuente** esta bajo en control del compilador, y tu, al escribirlo, lo haces poniendo instrucciones **una a continuación de la otra**. El compilador asume que, si tu asignas un valor a una variable y lo lees **cierto número de instrucciones despues**, sin modificaciones entre medias, no tiene que ir buscarlo a la RAM, puesto que **no ha sido modificado desde su asignación**. `volatile` avisa al compilador de que esa asunción no es correcta, y el valor puede haber cambiado **sin el saberlo**.

Comment: Bien, y eso no entra en conflicto con lo que he dicho. `volatile` se usa para indicar que el compilador no debe asumir cosas (que asume para generar código más eficiente).

Comment: Todo esto venia a cuento de tu respuesta: -"En realidad, cualquier dato podría ser modificado por otro código que no tengas en cuenta, aunque no esté marcado como volatile."-. Entendí que los datos se podian modificar **por tu código** sin que el compilador lo notara. Disculpa si no te entendí bien.